# Directive not working in application

Tags: javascript, angular

I can't figure out how to get directives working in my app. I want to apply a directive to a component, this is it in it's simplest form.

```
import {Directive, HostBinding} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[directiveSelector]'
})

export class FirstDirective {

  @HostBinding() innerText = 'not working';

}
```

...

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  template: `
    <h1 directiveSelector>Test</h1>`
})

export class HomeComponent {

}
```

...

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeModule } from "./home/home.module";
import { FirstDirective } from './directives/first.directive';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HomeModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FirstDirective
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Does anyone know what I am missing here? Home renders fine, and is a component wrapped in a module. Also, I cannot get a debugger or alert to fire off in the directive - may be a problem with the template binding?

Comment: Don't you need parentheses: `@HostBinding() innerText;`? Do you get any warnings/errors when building or in the console when you visit the site?

Comment: No, no errors. I don't think the directive is running at all though, and I'm not sure why. Yes it has parentheses, these must have gotten lost while pasting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the `FirstDirective` in your `HomeModule`, that should take care of it. Here I assume that your `HomeComponent` is part of `homemodule`.

Tried leaving it out myself from a module, and it produced no error but also didn't work.

Comment: what is his directive supposed to do ?

Comment: Well based on the code OP provided, it does nothing else than output 'not working' in the view.

Comment: Ah nice one AJT, I'd thought the modules would inherit from the root module but I was completely wrong! Thanks for your help :)